# Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /home/user/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 62

Tags: php, function, deprecated, ereg-replace

When I type my Website URL It's all right. But When I press the sub-category to view the inner content then the problem is occur. There is 5 folder in my public_html..

They are:

1.admin

2.avatars

3.FTP

4.images

5.includes

and some php files. This is a script.

I can't php.

#### There's some Error...

Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 62

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/phpflickr/phpFlickr.php on line 91

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/phpflickr/phpFlickr.php on line 330

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/phpflickr/phpFlickr.php on line 399

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/phpflickr/phpFlickr.php on line 468

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/phpflickr/PEAR/HTTP/Request.php on line 228

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/phpflickr/PEAR/HTTP/Request.php on line 324

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/phpflickr/PEAR/HTTP/Request.php on line 602

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/phpflickr/PEAR/HTTP/Request.php on line 621

Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class Net_URL in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/phpflickr/PEAR/Net/URL.php on line 122

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/phpflickr/PEAR/HTTP/Request.php on line 590

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/phpflickr/PEAR/HTTP/Request.php on line 591

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/exwggayd/public_html/includes/phpflickr/PEAR/HTTP/Request.php on line 603

#

The function.php inside the "includes" folder...may be there is the problem. But When I reload the page Everything Seems allright.

Here is the Codes...Paste on Pastebin!!

## function.php# http://pastebin.com/PR4RKSJS

## phpFlickr.php# http://pastebin.com/zzaVehBx

## Request.php# hxxp://pastebin.com/MPfq5zAL

## URL.php# hxxp://pastebin.com/yDMvA7e5

Comment: If you "can't php" then do something else. You expect someone to solve your errors for free?

Answer (score 1):

You should use preg_replace() instead.

ereg_replace() is now deprecated : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

It's a warning about using old function "ereg_replace", which could be easilly replaced by preg_replace.

For example, the code at line#62 of yours functions.php file:

```
    $string = ereg_replace(' +', ' ', trim($string));
```

could be replaced to:

```
    $string = preg_replace('# +#', ' ',trim($string));
```

where '#' - is a regular expresiion start and end sign, you can use "/", "|" or some others special signs instead of it ('/' it not recommended in your case, because it require to escape '/' characters in the regexp string, and, as you are "cant php", this could be difficult to you)

Other lines with "ereg_replace" can be fixed just the same way